# covariance matrix by group

Tags: r, matrix, covariance

I have been able to calculate covariance for my large data set with:

> cov(MyMatrix, use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson")

This provided the covariance table I was looking for, as well as dealing with the NA issues that are throughout my data. For a deeper analysis, however, I want to create covariance matrices that deal separately with the 800+ groups I have in my data set (some have 40+ observations, others only 1). I tried (from http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg86328.html):

> lapply(list(cov), by, data = MyMatrix[8:13], INDICES = MyMatrix["Group"])

Which gave me the following error:

> Error in tapply(seq_len(6L), list(`MyMatrix["Group"]` = NA_real_), function (x)  : 
>     arguments must have same length

This made me think the issue with the code involved the missing NA data, so I tried incorporating the "use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson"" phrase into the lapply code and can't get it to work. I'm not sure the best place for it, so I tried sticking it everywhere:

> lapply(list(cov), use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson"),by,data=MyMatrix[8:13], INDICES = MyMatrix["Group"])
>
> lapply(list(cov),by,data=PhenoMtrix[8:13], INDICES = PhenoMtrix["Group"], use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson")

This is obviously sloppy and doesn't work, so I'm a little stuck. Thanks in advance for your help!

My data is formatted as such:

> Group      HML       RML        FML       TML       FHD     BIB
>
> ```
>  1      323.50    248.75     434.50    355.75    46.84    NA
>
>  2        NA      238.50     441.50    353.00    45.83    277.0
>
>  2      309.50    227.75     419.00    332.25    46.39    284.0
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be *much* better if you provided an example of your data (or all of it), but since you didn't,

```
# create sample data
set.seed(1)
MyMatrix <- data.frame(group=rep(1:5, each=100),matrix(rnorm(2500),ncol=5))
# generate list of covariance matrices by group
cov.list <- lapply(unique(MyMatrix$group),
                   function(x)cov(MyMatrix[MyMatrix$group==x,-1],
                                  use="na.or.complete"))
cov.list[1]
# [[1]]
#             X1          X2          X3          X4          X5
# X1  0.80676209 -0.09541458 -0.12704666 -0.04122976  0.08636307
# X2 -0.09541458  0.93350463 -0.05197573 -0.06457299 -0.02203141
# X3 -0.12704666 -0.05197573  1.06030090  0.07324986  0.01840894
# X4 -0.04122976 -0.06457299  0.07324986  1.12059428  0.02385031
# X5  0.08636307 -0.02203141  0.01840894  0.02385031  1.11101410
```

In this example we create a dataframe called `MyMatrix` with a six columns. The first is `group` and the other five are `X1, X2, ... X5` and contain the data we wish to correlate. Hopefully, this is similar to the structure of your dataset.

The operative line of code is:

```
cov.list <- lapply(unique(MyMatrix$group),
                   function(x)cov(MyMatrix[MyMatrix$group==x,-1],
                                  use="na.or.complete"))
```

This takes a list of group id's (from `unique(MyMatrix$group)`) and calls the function with each of them. The function calculates the covariance matrix for all columns of `MyMatrix` except the first, for all rows in the relevant group, and stores the results in a 5-element list (there are 5 groups in this example).

Note: Regarding how to deal with NA. There are actually several options; you should review the documentation on ?cov to see what they are. The method chosen here, `use="na.or.complete"` includes in the calculation only rows which have *no NA values* in any of the columns. If, for a given group, there are no such rows, `cov(...)` returns NA. There are several other choices though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry about the lack of data, though your sample data was right on. Just to clarify, is missing data accounted for in this? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I just don't see anything I recognize that would obviously be a use function or na.rm or anything like that. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3288558 - It's not a dumb question. See my edits.

Comment: When I tried to make the cov.list with the "MyMatrix$group" group ID's, I was given the 'Error: $ is invalid for atomic vectors.' I then changed it to a data set, using CovDataM <- as.data.frame(MyMatrix), then retried the cov.list function with CovDataM$group and that worked.

Comment: Sorry, that posted too soon. I was going to say, but when I try to view the covariance matrices with cov(1) for example, I'm given an Error: supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x.' In an effort to get around this error I tried replacing the v$x function with v[['x']] as I saw suggested elsewhere, but it didn't like that either. Any suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. `cov(1)` passes the number `1` to the `cov(...)` function. `cov(...)` expects a matrix. On the other hand, the result of the code above is a list of covariance matrices, one for each group. So type cov.list[1] to see the covariance matrix for the first group.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. Unfortunately, using 
cov.list <- lapply(unique(CovDataM$group),function(x)cov(CovDataM[CovDataM$group==x,-1]))  gives me a NULL response, and continues to do so regardless of whether I add the use="na.or.complete" or the use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson" phrases to the end. My information has a lot of missing data (at least one per group, and often many), so I'd prefer to use this second method.

Comment: I don't want to keep eating up your time though, so I"m thinking of posting another question broadcasting my problem. If I do so, I was planning on citing your username with regards to the code you offered (I don't want to pretend to information I didn't come up with), but frankly I don't know if that's good Stackoverflow etiquette or not. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Re: etiquette, it's probably best to cite this question with a link to it, and state it's a followup. Alternatively, can you upload your dataset somewhere (Dropbox?) and provide a link. Then I can see why this isn't working for you. BTW: that is probably what you will be asked to do if you post a new question...

Answer (score 3):

you can also try:

```
  by(MyMatrix[-1],MyMatrix$group,cov,use="na.or.complete")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also first turn your dataframe into a list, and then use lapply to run the cov function on that list structure, and return a list of covariance matrices for each group.

Your example dataframe was too small to answer your question, so I used similar sample data by @jlhoward and some of your column names:

```
#Create sample dataframe and rename the columns based on the initial question 
MyDataframe <- data.frame(group=rep(1:5, each=10),matrix(rnorm(250),ncol=5))
colnames(MyDataframe) <- c("Group", "HML", "RML", "FML", "TML", "FHD")

#Split the dataframe columns HML, RML, FML, TML, and FHD into lists based on group membership, and call the new list MyList
MyList <- split(MyDataframe[ ,c("HML", "RML", "FML", "TML", "FHD")], list(Group = MyDataframe$Group))
> MyList
$`1`
          HML        RML        FML         TML         FHD
1   1.6806547 -1.2357861 -0.1438550 -1.79852015 -0.18745361
2  -1.2750024 -1.0973354  0.8654817  0.51666643  1.23240278
3   0.2381941 -1.1605690 -1.1124618 -1.24223216 -0.47014275
4  -0.6592671  0.6749256  0.3744053  2.82355336  0.04349764
5  -1.2026018  2.2036865 -0.6543408  0.05235647 -0.88794230
6   0.7946254  1.9786356 -0.1276282  0.37147386  2.23512260
7  -0.3166249 -1.0072974 -2.0800837 -0.31275558  0.88379182
8  -0.1662388  1.3819116 -3.1629656 -0.86033274 -0.31272981
9  -0.4666707 -0.8104205  1.0934703 -0.02459932 -0.35725108
10 -0.8385697  1.7204379 -0.3447757  0.18629448  0.42084553

$`2`
           HML         RML        FML           TML        FHD
11  0.03604007  0.58921306 -0.2066693 -1.0887154121  0.2790660
12  0.81767599  0.08703872 -0.1476078  0.1261011136  0.3525258
13 -0.19341506  0.31941568 -1.2553003  0.2419955263 -0.3152117
14  0.36065670 -0.77353050 -0.2166640  0.0001615059  0.7663386
15 -1.62885990  0.18124576  0.8299511 -1.0140332552 -0.9668448
16 -0.44847189 -1.57839214 -0.6470409 -0.0612936448 -0.3844145
17 -0.11144444 -0.65229817  0.6505128 -0.0882344334 -0.3144284
18  0.74339324  1.78857053 -1.2333200 -0.9063703037 -0.0765000
19  1.51958249 -0.56289571  0.2964601 -0.0287684624  0.3151081
20 -1.56974385  0.28559655 -2.7583618  0.3632164248 -0.1410783

$`3`
          HML         RML        FML         TML         FHD
21  1.8902244 -1.32617251 -0.3473238 -0.14714488 -0.20950269
22  0.7233421  1.87021160  0.5498787 -0.21878322 -0.25967403
23 -0.4488791  0.40916110 -0.2716354  0.68897421 -0.87347369
24 -0.4013050  0.41924705  0.6404477  0.81811788  1.24055660
25  1.1542181  0.75534163  0.1067173  0.32427043 -0.85858957
26 -1.3252742 -0.09989574  1.4557291 -0.62678378  0.04029924
27  0.2694684 -0.16238724 -0.6138011  0.07998383 -0.78157860
28 -0.8149025  0.77406215 -0.6921972  0.21223283 -0.86679556
29 -0.4916411 -0.80898776 -0.9372076 -1.44085453  1.18841866
30  0.3670508  1.45821533 -1.2531432  0.23593131 -1.17231457

$`4`
           HML        RML        FML         TML         FHD
31 -0.91753704  1.5976080  1.9286179 -0.88697107  0.85215534
32  0.57087719  1.2202687  0.5791964  1.98994106  0.68640384
33  0.79562327  1.0253044  0.5356456  0.31906648 -1.06342199
34 -0.06380725 -0.5774832  0.7260138 -0.93905123  1.88579741
35  0.24285367 -1.3862499  0.2853635 -1.27603774  0.07991027
36  1.15532419  0.4545112  0.3121971 -0.80544639 -0.74762482
37  1.30120698  1.3480126 -0.1012468  0.03093374 -0.74170584
38 -0.04423831  0.9100061 -2.1983937 -0.88974443  0.50814835
39 -1.71264891 -0.1225082  0.5095046 -1.28680921 -0.37710894
40 -0.11079800 -0.6806858 -0.9002725 -0.70797874  0.49889563

$`5`
          HML         RML        FML        TML         FHD
41 -0.6549724  0.77703431 -0.7953904 -0.7044253  0.73765368
42 -2.3945883  1.16952896  1.8286481 -0.8116904 -0.59562563
43  1.3470786 -0.26396886  0.3858448 -0.1839417  0.66618305
44 -0.4450848  0.71092152 -0.7665068 -0.1213066 -1.33159041
45  0.2621206 -0.05290252 -0.2817160 -1.1119020  0.53377605
46 -1.8713943 -0.82580895  0.5590292  0.5474239  1.85929122
47  2.1826177 -1.88918691 -0.2495949 -0.7371631  1.33998290
48 -0.2294448  1.04252185 -1.3311849  0.0447891  0.48173560
49  0.2250941 -0.37240902  1.1648265 -0.4848731 -0.06271555
50 -0.4131518 -0.94258989 -0.3291930 -1.7198636 -0.80485465

#Compute the covariance matrix for each group in MyList, and here I specify the columns, which is always good practice
within.group.cov <- lapply(MyList, function(x) cov(x[c("HML", "RML", "FML", "TML", "FHD")], use="pairwise.complete.obs"))
> within.group.cov
$`1`
           HML        RML        FML        TML       FHD
HML  0.8421194 -0.3185286 -0.1532037 -0.6192220 0.1086547
RML -0.3185286  2.1271906 -0.3640053  0.5995860 0.1025134
FML -0.1532037 -0.3640053  1.7151420  0.6879402 0.2133205
TML -0.6192220  0.5995860  0.6879402  1.5581052 0.2910293
FHD  0.1086547  0.1025134  0.2133205  0.2910293 0.8965167

$`2`
           HML         RML         FML         TML         FHD
HML 1.00082711  0.02754603  0.28260061  0.03354966  0.33759313
RML 0.02754603  0.84357799 -0.32547765 -0.24018033 -0.02572972
FML 0.28260061 -0.32547765  1.13751383 -0.22229766 -0.03210768
TML 0.03354966 -0.24018033 -0.22229766  0.29451851  0.06511133
FHD 0.33759313 -0.02572972 -0.03210768  0.06511133  0.24129973

$`3`
            HML         RML         FML         TML        FHD
HML  0.95281484 -0.06072793 -0.18608614  0.08682029 -0.2241560
RML -0.06072793  0.94498926  0.05826306  0.26708137 -0.3414530
FML -0.18608614  0.05826306  0.68405108  0.02649167  0.2239994
TML  0.08682029  0.26708137  0.02649167  0.43268293 -0.2285798
FHD -0.22415605 -0.34145303  0.22399939 -0.22857978  0.7388127

$`4`
           HML        RML         FML         TML         FHD
HML  0.8545644  0.2010881 -0.18227287  0.43631519 -0.31002651
RML  0.2010881  1.0269461  0.16025720  0.53798506 -0.20676662
FML -0.1822729  0.1602572  1.18667903  0.11072818  0.07572155
TML  0.4363152  0.5379851  0.11072818  0.99720184 -0.07098033
FHD -0.3100265 -0.2067666  0.07572155 -0.07098033  0.82212198

$`5`
           HML         RML         FML         TML         FHD
HML  1.8208574 -0.73730457 -0.43570215 -0.13051837  0.30984815
RML -0.7373046  0.98584765 -0.06674645  0.10796767 -0.43046406
FML -0.4357021 -0.06674645  0.93344577 -0.00659714 -0.03835305
TML -0.1305184  0.10796767 -0.00659714  0.40967714  0.26304517
FHD  0.3098481 -0.43046406 -0.03835305  0.26304517  0.97107321
```